# C# Pass Text back to Main Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm attempting to open a form get user input and pass that input back to the main form for adding to a List but I can't wrap my head around this any helpful advice would be grateful as to what I'm doing wrong!
Error I'm getting 
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
//Character Class
public class Character {
    private string _Name;

    public string Name {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return _Name;
    }
}

//Main Form1
        public List<Character> charList = new List<Character>();
        public EventHandler CharAdded; 

        public void GetData(string name) {
         Character c = new Character();
         c.Name = name;
         charList.Add(c);
       }

        private void btnCreateChar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        UserInputForm uif = new UserInputForm();

        //Subscribe to events
        CharAdded += uif.btnAdd_Click;

        //Call Event
        if (CharAdded != null) {
            CharAdded(this, new EventArgs());
        }

        //Show Form
        uif.Show();
    }

//UserInputForm
    public void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Form1 mainForm = sender as Form1;
        mainForm.GetData(txtName.Text); //Error on line
    }
```

Comment: Does your user input form have a text box and a button Add ? Well then where is it defined that the 'CharAdded' event will be triggered upon the click of Add button from child form ? Also please show the error stack and the line number where error occurs.

Comment: Is the "InitializeComponent" call properly done in UserInputForm's constructor? I'm assuming txtName is null where the error happens.

Comment: Please provide information about what `txtName` is.

Comment: is that not what is saying.
     //Subscribe to events
    CharAdded += uif.btnAdd_Click;
     //Call Event
     if (CharAdded != null) {
     CharAdded(this, new EventArgs());
      }

Comment: txtName.Text would be from a Textbox..

Comment: You should move the event to the UserInputForm. It's uncommon and confusing to register another object on one's own event. You register yourself on another object's events.

Comment: basically what needs to happen is Main Form1 button(btnCreate) opens userInputForm modeless, the user enters a value in TextBox(txtName) on UserInputForm and hits btnAdd. btnAdd press sends Text back to Form1 to be added to a List<Character>(CharList)

Comment: Your code run good for first time, but when the `btnAdd` hint in `UserInputForm` that exception is occurred, so seems you want to pass data to `charList` of `Form`, yes?

Comment: I guess I should clarify

Main Form1
- List<Character> string name, decimal level
- Button(btnAdd) Opens Form2 Modeless(.show() can spawn multiple)
Form2
-TextBox1 - Name
-TextBox2 - Level
-Button(btnAdd) - needs to send TextBox1 and Textbox2 creat a Character and send back to Form1 for adding to List<Character>

Answer (score 1):

In your btnAdd_Click handler, 'sender' is of type Form1. It is a reference to btnAdd which is type Button. So the line

Form1 mainForm = sender as Form1;

sets mainForm to null, hence your exception

But the main issue is your even handling is a bit backwards. The CharAdded even should exist in UserInputForm and triggered from btnAdd_Click on the UserInputForm.

Your code in mainform then becomes:

```
private void btnCreateChar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        UserInputForm uif = new UserInputForm();

        //Subscribe to events
        uif.CharAdded += Uif_CharAdded;

        //Show Form
        uif.Show();
}

// still in Form1
private void Uif_CharAdded(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  UserInputForm uif = (UserInputForm)sender;
  mainForm.GetData(uif.txtName.Text)
}
```

This code is still not great as it means that UserInputForm textName has to be made public but hopefully it shows you which way around to write the event code.

Comment: Ah, right. When the user clicks the Add() button. I was thinking about the first time it's called, where it _is_ Form1. Weird way of using an event, anyway.

Comment: Actually, looking again I think I'm wrong. But the code is weird and I've only just woken up

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an event handler for Add button of User Input form and you have to add subscription to this handler upon initialization of its own form and not the main form. You can also access charList from child form.
Then upon the Add button click in child form, you can add new character to charList.

```
public UserInputForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    btnAdd.Click += btnAdd_Click;
}

public void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs E)
{
    Form2 parent = (this.Parent as Form2);
    parent.charList.Add(txtName.Text);
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some implications with your code:

1- `GetData` is not clear what is should do, get the name of control in `UserInputForm` or the text of `txtName` , seems you want pass the text to `Form1`

2- If the first one is true then you should not complex your code just do these:

```
public partial class UserInputForm : Form
{
    public new  Form1 Parent { get; set; }//If you want to replace Parent prop use new keyword otherwise rename Parent prop 
    public UserInputForm(Form1 parent)
    {
        Parent = parent; 
        InitializeComponent();
    } 
    public void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        Parent.SetData(txtName.Text); //Error on line
    } 
}
```

in `Form1`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{ 
    public List<Character> charList = new List<Character>(); 
    public void SetData(string name)
    {
        Character c = new Character();
        c.Name = name;
        charList.Add(c);
    } 
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserInputForm uif = new UserInputForm(this);
        uif.Show();
    }  
}
```

4- but if you want to add controls name to `charList` and then get their values 
do something like, define a prop in `From` as child so would be like:

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public List<Character> charList = new List<Character>();
    public UserInputForm Child { get; set; }
    public void SetData(string name)
    {
        Character c = new Character();
        c.Name = name;
        charList.Add(c);
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } 
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserInputForm uif = new UserInputForm(this);
        uif.Show();
    }  
}
```

and UserInputForm:

```
public partial class UserInputForm : Form
{
    public new Form1 Parent { get; set; }//If you want to replace Parent prop use new keyword otherwise rename Parent prop 
    public UserInputForm(Form1 parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
        parent.Child = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Parent.SetData(txtName.Name); //Error on line
    }
}
```

5- one thing more if you want the data of controls stored in `charList` , suppose in a button click in `Form1`:

```
private void btnGetUserInputTextBoxData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var controls = Child.Controls;
    foreach (Character controlName in charList)
    {
        var ctr = (TextBox)controls.Find(controlName.Name, false).FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(ctr.Text);
    }
}
```